# Replacing carets in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace multiple carets (^) in a string with spaces in Javascript. Following the w3schools entry on replace(), I used this code:

```
var str = "Salt^Lake^City, UT";
var result = str.replace(/^/g, " ");
```

However, value of `result` is " Salt^Lake^City, UT". One caret is replaced when I run this code:

```
var result = str.replace("^", " ");
```

but I want to replace all of an arbitrary number of carets. Is there something obvious I'm missing about globally replacing in Javascript? I could write a function using `str.replace("^", " ");` to remove all the carets, but I'd rather use the built-in global replace.

Comment: Don't consult w3schools. Some information on that webpage is wrong (see this for an explanation: http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `^` character matches the start of the string in a regex, so you need to escape it so it will be treated as a literal character. That is why in your example, the result string has a new space added at the start of the string.

```
var result = str.replace(/\^/g, " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use another handy way which is roundabout.

```
var result = str.split('^').join(' ') ;
```